# Two radio buttons selcted at the same time

Tags: jquery, html

I have an ascx partial view in my ASP.NET MVC application. I `load` the content of this partial view using `jquery.load()`. The partial view populates radio buttons which are associated to a certain class id which I handle its click event through `$.live("click", function(){})` but I end up being able to select both radio buttons at the same time! i.e. I select the first radio button, click the second, and I get both of them selected. Any ideas?

My partial view looks like this:

```
<table>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.RadioButton(item.Id.ToString(), item.Id, new {@class="radioCat" })%>
            <%: item.Name %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>
</table>
```

And my jquery event handler..

```
$(".radioCat").live("click", function () { alert('clicked'); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Radio buttons needs to be in the same `Group`; add this.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Is that an html attribute I have to add to the radio button?

Comment: Set the `name` attribute same for both buttons. It is the name of the group: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Comment: That still doesnt work with me:  <%: Html.RadioButton(item.Id.ToString(), item.Id, new {@class="radioCat",name="test" })%>